# Is there a way to compare values of one column and then update a list based on if a condition is met?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a data frame of datetimes, pay, and duration. Duration is the difference between the two datetime columns and pay is what I paid a provider to complete a service. I'm trying to iterate through each value in the column 'duration' and if the value is >= 100 then add to the list newPrice a value which is the corresponding value in the payColumn*.99

I have tried building nested if/for loops, lambda statements, and building my own function. I'm transitioning from R to Python in my job and am not doing well at the moment to translate this process into Python code.

```
 duration = [122.0, 48.0, 102.0]
 Pay = [50.00, 26.49, 36.80]
 newPay = []

 for i in df['duration']:
     if i >= 100:
          newPay.append(df['Pay']*.99)
     elif i >= 50 and i <= 99.99:
          newPay.append(df['Pay']*.98)
     else:
          newPay.append(df['Pay']*.97)
 print(newPay)
```

I expect newPay to be populated with the original pay multiplied by the modifier

Answer (score 0):

```
duration = [122.0, 48.0, 102.0]
pay = [50.00, 26.49, 36.80]
new_pay = []

for i, value in enumerate(duration):
    if value >= 100:
        new_pay.append(pay[i]*.99)
    elif value >= 50 and value <= 99.99:
        new_pay.append(pay[i]*.98)
    else:
        new_pay.append(pay[i]*.97)
print(new_pay)
```

Comment: I really appreciate it! I was unaware of 'enumerate' and didn't know that using [i] would work the same as it does in R loops. Thanks again for the help!